# arithmetic operation return negative value

Tags: sh, integer-arithmetic

I have an arithemic operation between two big value as following :

```
#!/bin/sh
a=$((0x1000000*0x0001d2))
echo $a
# result: -771751936 
# wrong may the root cause is the size of variable
```

Have any solution to fix that? 
NOTE: I'm using a very limited shell (sh).

Comment: Your shell doesn't support unbounded integers; there is some maximum value it can represent, and if you were to add 1 to that, you would get the *smallest* value. You are seeing the result of that overflow.

Comment: `awk 'END{ printf( "%.4f\n", 0x1000000*0x0001d2)}' /dev/null` ? Returns `7818182656.0000` (no idea if that is correct ;-) ).  Good luck.
`

Comment: You can use dc too : dc -e '16 i 1000000 1D2 * p'